# Primefaces commandButton doesn't invoke action when there's a script inside the same form

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using a script to add "maskMoney" to an input field which is inside a p:dialog. I found out I need to put the script inside the form otherwise it won't work. The problem is, when the script is inside the form, my p:comandButton doesn't invoke the action, if I move the script to outside the form, the p:commandButton works, but my script doesn't (mask is not applied).

If I add "process="@this", commandbutton works fine, but obviously doesn't submit the form, just invoke the action.

I've tried to use "partialSubmit" processing just the components instead ofwhole form, but no success.

```
<h:form id="inserir_valor" >
    <script>
        jQuery(function($)
        {$("input.dinheiro").maskMoney({showSymbol:true, symbol:"R$", decimal:",", thousands:"."});
                    });
    </script>
    <p:dialog id="inserir_valor_tela" header="Inserindo..." widgetVar="tela_valor_pgto" resizable="false" modal="true" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel value="Valor:"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{pedidosBean.valorFatura}" id="valor_inserido" size="10" required="true" styleClass="dinheiro"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel value="Prazo:"/>
            <p:inputText id="entrada_prazo" value="#{pedidosBean.codigoPrazo}" size="4" 
                    onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { onchange(); return false; }">
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{pedidosBean.carregarPrazo}" update=":inserir_valor:prazo_menu"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="prazo_menu" value="#{pedidosBean.faturaSelecionada.prazo.codigo}" required="true">                         
                <f:selectItems value="#{pedidosBean.listaPrazos}" var="prazo"
                        itemValue="#{prazo.codigo}" itemLabel="#{prazo.prazo}"/>
                <p:ajax listener="#{pedidosBean.prazoSelecionadoMenu()}" update="inserir_valor" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Adicionar" partialSubmit="true" action="#{pedidosBean.adicionarPgto()}" class="botao_sub_menu" 
                update=":faturamento:prazos_faturamento" process=":inserir_valor:valor_inserido @this" 
                oncomplete="PF('tela_valor_pgto').hide();"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I've tried put the script in a separate file and call using h:outputscript target="head" at the end of the h:body but it doesn't work too.

I'm using primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2 and there are no error messages in eclipse neither in chrome.

How do I use my script with my button?

Comment: It could be JSF itself rejecting your input values in the validation phase. For an efficient JSF debugging, set the PROJECT_STAGE context param to true and add a `p:messages` tag in your view.

Comment: @xtremebiker: to 'DEVELOPMENT' you mean?

Comment: Why don't you use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/inputNumber/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: @XtremeBiker It doesn't show me any error. Still doesn't fire the action.